# Can't send request to Odoo

Tags: angular, odoo

I'm trying to connect my angular2 app with Odoo using this script :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [OdooRPCService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor( private odooRPC: OdooRPCService){
    this.odooRPC.init({
      odoo_server: "https://server.name"
    });
    this.odooRPC.login('xx', 'admin', 'admin').then(res => {
      console.log('login success');
    }).catch( err => {
      console.error('login failed', err);
    })
  }
}
```

but I keep getting this error in my browser console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://server.name . Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: That means that server.name should provide access to localhost to access server.name's services. You can add 'localhost' to allow access and just for test purpose, you can try enabling CORS in chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: than you , but I already have that in my apache server's configuration : Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" , so I don't think that's the problem :/ , I tried your solution though , but it's not working !

Comment: Any updates on this? I see that you've gone one step further and been able to create a new project in odoo using this lib. So what was the changes you made to get the connection right?

Comment: @YaseenShareef , I had to make more changes on the Odoo server's configuration. you can find them here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346683/how-create-a-new-project-in-odoo-via-my-angular2-app/43370824?noredirect=1#comment80841082_43370824

Comment: Thanks Maria, I already did that in the wsgi_server.py file and got it working.