# How create a new project in Odoo via my angular2 app?

Tags: angular, odoo

I am building an app with angular2 that has to be able to fetch and insert data into Odoo database , in that purpose ,  I am using angular2-odoo-jsonrpc : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-odoo-jsonrpc

and I was able to get all the data I needed from Odoo , but , I also want to be able to insert data in the Odoo database , so I used to following code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
providers: [OdooRPCService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

projectList;
ngOnInit(){
let self = this;
self.projectList = [];
self.odooRPC.init({
odoo_server: "https://demo"
});
self.odooRPC.login('DB', 'admin', 'admin').then(res => {
console.log('login success');
}).catch( err => {
console.error('login failed', err);
})
self.odooRPC.call('project.project', 'create',"" ,{ 'name' :'New project'})
.then((projects:any) => {
if(projects){
self.projectList = projects;
}
})
}
constructor( private odooRPC: OdooRPCService){
}}
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 321, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 964, in call
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 514, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 888, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 880, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'
```

I suppose I didn't know how to use the call function : call(model, method, args, kwargs) . Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could find the right arguments for the call method and it worked and I could add a new project to Odoo database :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [OdooRPCService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  projectList;
  ngOnInit(){
    let self =  this;
    self.projectList = [];
    self.odooRPC.init({
      odoo_server: "https://demo"
    });
    self.odooRPC.login('DB', 'admin', 'admin').then(res => {
      console.log('login success');
    }).catch( err => {
      console.error('login failed', err);
    })
    **self.odooRPC.call('project.project', 'create',[{name:'New'}] , {})**
        .then((projects:any) => {
      if(projects){
        self.projectList = projects;
      }
    })
  }
  constructor( private odooRPC: OdooRPCService){
  }}
```

Comment: Hi Maria,

Did you happen to run across the following issue initially while trying to connect to an odoo instance via angular?:


XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://odoo-server/web/session/authenticate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: you should add this section: # Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, x-openerp-session-id, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, x-openerp-session-id, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

Comment: it's the Odoo server's configuration

Comment: Hi Maria, I'm facing a strange issue on the angular page that fetches data from Odoo and shows it. The first time the page loads, it shows the access control error, but when it's refreshed it fetches and shows without any problem. The headers are set properly from the odoo side response, dont know what exactly the issue is.

Comment: And when we are implementing it this way, isn't there a security issue that the dbname, uname and pwd are available in the request publicly? Isn't that a major security issue?